# How to hide seams in the open?

Tags: uv

I am strongly seeking a way to hide seems that are out in the open. Sometimes you just can't hide a seam and I am fairly confident there is a way to hide UV seams no matter the placement, perhaps through multiple normal bakes or some sort of method. I have searched the earth's end trying to find a clear tutorial on such a method and have yet to discover a very thorough clear technique. I beg of anyone to give me the secret! :) Again please do not talk to me about hiding seams through placement as I know how to place them in good areas, sometimes I want no sacrifice or can't hide them. So again to my point, can anyone provide me with a technique?